# No w/s in iostat output even though wMB/s is high

Tags: storage-area-network, multipath, iostat, block-device

I am trying to format a 2 TB SAN based block device (`/dev/mapper/mpathb`). Even though, `mke2fs` has been running since over one hour without completing, `iostat -z -x -m 10` output in a separate terminal shows a surprising thing: There are no completed write requests (`w/s`) even though number of sectors written to disk (`wMB/s`) is pretty high.

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util

dm-0      0.00     0.00    0.00    0.10     0.00   204.80 4194304.00     1.00 11036.00 10000.00 100.00
dm-2      0.00     0.00    0.00    0.10     0.00   204.80 4194304.00     1.00 11036.00 10000.00 100.00
```

Hardly anything changes in `iostat` output: write speed remains high while number of sectors written remains zero! Any ideas?

Comment: Still waiting? Are your paths up? What does `multipath -ll` say?

Comment: No, filesystem creation did complete after several hours. I checked the write speed on the mounted filesystem. It looks to be fine now.